# How to move rows and columns of certain indices to either end of matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix let it be

```
A = 100x100 matrix
```

and a vector

```
B = [ 2 7 23 45 55 67 79 88 92]
```

And I want to bring these rows and columns to the end of the array meaning the last 9x9 block in `A` to be the rows and columns of `B`. (the last row of `A` should now be row 92 and the last column should be column 92)

Any ideas?

Comment: Then, is B the diagonal of a 9*9 matrix?

Comment: no B is a vector indicating which rows and columns I want to reorder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to change the order of the rest of the rows/columns, let's start with arranging all the indices:

```
n = size(A,1);
allIdx = 1:n;
allIdx(B) = []; %// discard B from their original place
allIdx = [allIdx, B]; %// put B at the end
newA = A(allIdx, allIdx); %// Ta-DA!
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with [**`setxor`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html):

```
A = reshape(1:10000,100,100);     %// matrix with linear indices
B = [ 2 7 23 45 55 67 79 88 92];  %// rows and cols to move to the end

idx = [setxor(1:size(A,1),B) B];  %// index vector for rows and cols
out = A(idx,idx)
```

For the simpler test case of `B = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ];` you get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `ismember`

```
B = [ 2 7 23 45 55 67 79 88 92];
oldIdx = 1:100;
newIdx = [oldIdx(~ismember(oldIdx,B)),B];
out = A(newIdx,newIdx);
```